# What is a valid parent for get_terms()?

Tags: php, mysql

```
get_terms($taxonomy, array('parent' => $parent));
```

This works for some parents and returns an empty array for others. I checked if a term with the parent ID exists and if the same ID is in the 'parent' field of the child term's taxonomy. Even copy-pasted directly from the database. Is there anything else? I don't see a difference between the parents that work and the ones that don't.

edit: All invisible terms appear the moment I add a new term via the dashboard. Turns out the problem was that there is a function `wp_insert_term()` for adding terms and I was using `$wpdb->insert` and manually inserting the term and the taxonomy, which makes a difference, somehow.

Comment: Your question makes no sense at all. Please rephrase

Comment: What is the output of  `get_terms` and what type is the variable `$parent` ?

Comment: @PieterGoosen Let's say there are a few terms with a parent with an ID of 1 and a few terms with a parent with an ID of 5, both have the taxonomy "board". `get_terms("board", array('parent' => 1));` works and `get_terms("board", array('parent' => 5));` doesn't. A term with an ID of 1 exists and a term with an ID of 5 exists. Why would the second code not work? What makes a term valid in wordpress' eyes?

Comment: @Laxmana It's a wordpress function. [It returns an array of term objects](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms). `$parent` is an integer.

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase my question. I know it is a wordpress function. I meant what is the output of `get_terms` when it "fails". Is a WP_Error or an empty array?

Comment: Are you sure that parent with ID 5 has children?

Comment: It is impossible to say why the terms with parent 5 does not work. There is really to much info missing from your question. Are you sure there is no external filters that is acting on `get_terms()`. Have you tested this on a bundled theme. For as long as a term is the db and associated with a valid taxonomy, it should work regardless. Just note, if you have your code hooked to anything before `init`, `get_terms()` will return an error stattng that the taxonomy is invalid

Comment: @Laxmana It returns an empty array. I literally open the table, copy a term's parent, check if the parent exists, and paste it in the code, and it returns an empty array.

Comment: OK, that makes a huge difference, that is why you should never ever use SQL instead of build in functions. You should post your update as an answer and accept it

Comment: @PieterGoosen I exported the term and taxonomy tables before adding terms both ways and the types of differences were the same though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`wp_insert_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) instead of `$wpdb->insert` for adding new terms.

Comment: if you look at the source code for `wp_insert_terms`, it does a huge amount of work before a term is successfully added, which `$wpdb->insert` does not do. Even when something goes wrong, the term is inserted with `$wpdb->insert`, and this causes issues with relationships. The Wordpress functions might look heavily overboard, but it is done for a reason. Never use plain SQL to do complex stuff like inserting terms

Answer (score 1):

The only variable which can really have an effect on the result as you described, is taxonomy. If you have verified that there are terms with a parent of `1` and a parent of `5`, and `get_terms()` only returns terms for terms with a parent of `1`, it can only mean that term `1` and term `5` belongs to different taxonomies. `get_terms()` will only return results if the term data passed is associated with the passed taxonomy.

You need to remember, **all** terms, regardless of taxonomy, are stored in the `wp_terms` table. Relationships are stored in the `wp_term_taxonomy` table. This is where the term's taxonomy and parent is saved.

Here is a small script which you can run on any page. This will print all the taxonomies and all terms associated with that taxonomy and also print the parent ID if the terms aren't top level terms. You can use this to "debug" your issue

```
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies(); 
if ( $taxonomies ) {
    foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
        if ( $terms ) {
            echo '<strong>' . strtoupper( $taxonomy ) . '</strong></br>';
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $parent_id = ( 0 != $term->parent ) ? ' and has a parent ID of ' . $term->parent : '';
                echo 'Term '. $term->name . ' ID ' . $term->term_id . ' belongs to the taxonomy '. $taxonomy . $parent_id . '</br>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know about `wp_terms` and `wp_term_taxonomy`, can't really check all of them with your code, since they are a few thousand, but still checked the taxonomies in case there are two with similar names, but no, every term I am working with belongs to the same taxonomy. I thought it could be because the IDs for the problematic ones are bigger than 9999, but I made a new one via the admin dashboard and it's showing normally.

Comment: Then you have an issue with a bad filter in your theme or plugin as this has nothing to do with default behavior. WordPress does not "favor" certain terms, they all work exactly the same, specially within the same taxonomy. Start by clearing ALL caches, browser and plugin, if the problem persist, start by deactivating one plugin at a time and check when the problem stops. If this does not work, change to a bundled theme. Also, download a plugin to repair and optimize your db, there might be misplaced data as well.